# CSS is not affecting generated PDF in wkhtmltopdf in ubuntu

Tags: html, wkhtmltopdf, phpwkhtmltopdf

I am using **OS: Ubuntu 16.04**. I have integrated this package in my laravel application. PDF is generating but no CSS affect on this generated file.

In **OS: windows**, Everything is working perfectly.

In **OS: Ubuntu 16.04**,

- Generated PDF is balck & white.
- Color, Background color, font styling everything is removed. :-(

[HTML view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY7pM.pngfile:///home/novapex/Downloads/mmm.4.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Style was applying but color and background color were not applying. Just making all `colors` and `background-colors` properties `!important` works.

```
p { color:green !important; }
```

***Solved !!!***